# Is many to optional one relation possible?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following situation: a `Device` can have multiple `Subscriptions`, but a `Subscription` has maximum one `Device` or none at all. In my database `Subscriptions` has a foreign key `DeviceID` which is `Nullable` (not the `ID` property in `Device` class). At the moment for some reason the following fluent code works:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Subscriptions)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Device)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

If I choose WithOptional(), which should be logical, I get errors. The error is this ModelvalidationError:

> Additional information: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> Entities.Device_Subscriptions: : Multiplicity conflicts with
>   the referential constraint in Role 'Device_Subscriptions_Source' in
>   relationship 'Device_Subscriptions'. Because all of the properties in
>   the Dependent Role are non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal
>   Role must be '1'.

However If I now query for example (with the `.WithRequired(...)` code)

```
db.Subscriptions.Where(s => s.DeviceID == null).Count();
```

I get zero, although there is one `Subscription` in my database with `DeviceID` null.

(partial)Model for `Device`:

```
public class Device
{
    public Device() : base()
    {
        Subscriptions = new HashSet<Subscription>();
    }
    [Key]
    public decimal DeviceID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions {get; set;}
}
```

(partial)Model for `Subscription`:

```
public partial class Subscription
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public decimal? DeviceID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public virtual Device {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the [Key] attribute on the DeviceID column on the Subscription class? I don't think you can have part of your Key as Nullable, but I honestly don't know

Comment: DeviceID in subscription class is nullable foreign key to Device in the database and also it's indexed together with Type

Comment: @AlexanderDerck [Key] is used for Primary Key, and it can't be nullable. For Foreign Keys you should use [ForeingKey] instead

Comment: @AlexanderDerck as Fabio says, you're incorrectly using the [Key] attribute here. In addition to the [ForeignKey] attribute, if you're using EF6.1 there is an [Index] attribute that might help https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx

Comment: @Vlad274 Thanks, I will try to use the `Index` attribute tomorrow (home atm), the strange thing is that this class was auto-generated by Database first. Maybe `DeviceID` wasn't nullable at first but somebody changed it, I can only check tomorrow I'm afraid

Comment: I have this feeling somebody has been messing with the database, it's strange that there's only one record with deviceID null

Comment: @Vlad274 It was exactly what you said, the `Index` attribute that fixed it. It never occurred to me that someone would have changed the database so I thought my models were still correct. If you want post an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[Key]` attribute is used to declare the Primary Key of an Entity. Having a nullable value as part of a PK doesn't really make sense.

From the comments, it seems that what you're really looking to accomplish is having an Index on (DeviceID, Type). In EF 6.1, they added the `[Index]` attribute which should accomplish this. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx#IndexMulti)